# Get the last frame color from GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to processing a texture in the Fragment Shader. However, current frame should base on last frame information, such as neighbor positions. So I need write current frame into one place/buffur/object and read it in next loop.

Can someone give me a direction about my requirement?

Comment: How is the procedure you described not working for you?

Comment: Here is just a idea. I don't know exactly what technology I should use.

Answer (score 2):

Use Frame Buffer Objects. Create two FBOs into which you render alternatingly, each time binding the other one as texture for sourcing the data.